# How can I solve/simplify a relationship with 3 entities where one is reflexive?

Tags: database-design, relational-database, entity-relationship

I haven't been able to find a solution to this problem in books nor in the web.

I have three entities: user, XML, XSDT. I'm trying to reflect using a relationship that a user, applying a xsdt to a xml, produces a new xml.

So, xml + user + xsdt = a new xml.

Considering that the xml entity intervenes two times (the base file that is extracted from there, and the product that is stored also there) should this be a n-ary relationship with four elements? (counting XML twice)?

Honestly, I have no idea of how to reflect this, nor how to transform the relation into the relational model later.

Comment: From a purist standpoint you shouldn't store the new XML as it can always be generated by xml + user+xsdt.  The only time a value which can be calculated should ever be stored, is if there are performance issues in the overhead of calculating the value.  In that case you would use a computed column or function based index or other depending on RDBMS being used.

Comment: The problem with that idea (not storing the xml), is that this "generation" can add up multiple times. So, the new xml can be used as a base to generate another xml with a new combination. Then the result can be combined again...